# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I am getting the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

My Piece of code that is returning this error is this:

```
public boolean checkAttendance(String userid,String currentdate){
        boolean status=false;
        List attendanceList=new ArrayList();
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "select userid from Attendance where userid='"+ userid +"' and date='"+currentdate+"'";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql); 
            attendanceList = (ArrayList) query.list();  //This Line returning the error
            if(attendanceList.size()>0)
            {
                status=true;
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }       

        return status;
    }
```

I have tried to enable view sql in my Context.xml file

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=true;
            </value>
        </property>
```

I cannot see the sql getting executed and I do not Know why this error is coming because my table and Fields are correct. Please Help. Am using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select userid from Attendance where userid...` is SQL and not valid HQL.

You should change it to something like

`select a.userid from Attendance a where a.userid = :userid and a.date=:currentdate`

OT - it is a good idea to always use query parameters and not string concatenation. Using parameters is safer and more efficient. See [**this article**](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter) for a good explanation.

EDIT: the validity of the query string is checked early. If it is invalid, no SQL creation takes place. If no SQL is created, there is nothing to execute. The `show_sql` flag therefore has no effect for invalid queries.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this. Any idead why I can't see my hls gettng executed?

Comment: @Stanley I may have not made myself clear enough or maybe I am misunderstanding you - the query string is invalid - this is why it is not executed

Comment: That's fine sir, but I should be able to see the query the Application is trying to execute so as to get that error as I have set My ` hibernate.show_sql=true;` right?